# wso2 analytics HA configuration doesn't work

Tags: load-balancing, wso2-api-manager, wso2, high-availability

in the fallowing picture I showed my setup :
[[image]]
wso2 api manager(3.2.0) configuration document said :

```
Configure the following event receiver configuration groups.
    [[apim.analytics.url_group]]
    analytics_url = 
    ["tcp://10.192.69.103:7612","tcp://10.192.69.104:7612"]
    analytics_auth_url = 
    ["ssl://10.192.69.103:7712","ssl://10.192.69.104:7712"]
    type = "loadbalance"
```

I added this configuratin to both api manager nodes and pointed to node 1 and 2 of analytics on 7612 and 7712 ports and type is loadbalance .
and below is my analytics dashboard config :

```
## Authentication configuration
 auth.configs:
kmDcrUrl: https://APIM-NODE1-IP:9443/client- 
registration/v0.17/register
kmDcrUrl: https:// APIM-NODE2-IP:9443/client- 
registration/v0.17/register
kmTokenUrlForRedirection: https://APIM-Domain/oauth2
kmTokenUrl: https:// APIM-NODE1-IP:9443/oauth2
kmTokenUrl: https:// APIM-NODE2-IP:9443/oauth2
baseUrl: https://APIM-Analtics-domain:9643  
publisherUrl: https:// APIM-NODE1-IP:9443
publisherUrl: https:// APIM-NODE2-IP:9443
devPortalUrl: https:// APIM-NODE1-IP:9443
devPortalUrl: https:// APIM-NODE2-IP:9443
externalLogoutUrl: https://APIM-Domain:9443/oidc/logout
```

and I also change the related wso2 API manager carbon setting for analytics
my problem is when I stop API-M node 1 and Also Analytics node 2, node 2 of API-M can't connect to Analytics node1,actully the load balacing doesn't work .what is the problem or missing part in my configs , really appreciate if anaybody can help me guys .thanx so much.