# how to connect WSO2 Analytics Workers as Active-Active configuration to two dashboards?

Tags: wso2, analytics

I read Configuring Analytics Workers as Active-Active in wso2 documentation and it was not clear for me.can anyone explain more clear for me ?(how to connect only one dashboard to 2 or more analytics workers?)
and another question : is it possible to have two dashboards connect to wso2 workers in Configuring Analytics Workers as Active-Active ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Analytics dashboard is stored as a sub-profile of the APIM analytics. You can configure a separate Analytics node as the dashboard for both worker nodes. You simply need to connect the dashboard to the required databases. The dashboard will read the statistics (published from the worker nodes) in the Analytics database and display the statistics on the dashboard. You can use the configurations mentioned in [1] to point to the same databases.

As the dashboard is used only to render the data, there is no active-active or active-passive concept. However, based on the High-availability (HA) requirement it can be configured as Active-Active or Active-Passive by defining the loadbalance configuration.

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/#step-42-configure-the-analytics-dashboard

Comment: thanx @lakshitha   
can you guide me with two dashboard node setup,we have a domain name for two API manager nodes and a domain name for two analytics node(loadBalance).how to setup two dashboard(what configuration must be changed) and below is my dashboard conf.am I right or no ? :

Comment: link to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72346657/wso2-analytics-ha-configuration-doesnt-work